# How to parse this xml using linq

Tags: xml, linq

I have the following xml that I need to parse and get values using linq

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<questestinterop xmlns="http://www.imsglobal....." xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org...." xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/.....xsd">
  <assessment ident="gh" title="Sample">
    <qtimetadata>
      <qtimetadatafield>
        <fieldlabel>cc_maxattempts</fieldlabel>
        <fieldentry>1</fieldentry>
      </qtimetadatafield>
    </qtimetadata>
    <section ident="rs">
      <item ident="ghg" title="Question">
        <itemmetadata>
          <qtimetadata>
            <qtimetadatafield>
              <fieldlabel>question_type</fieldlabel>
              <fieldentry>yyy</fieldentry>
            </qtimetadatafield>
            <qtimetadatafield>
               <fieldlabel>points_possible</fieldlabel>
               <fieldentry>1</fieldentry>
            </qtimetadatafield>
            <qtimetadatafield>
                <itemmetadata>
                <presentation>
                  .........
                </presentation>
      </item>
      <item ident="hj" title="Question">
        ....
      </item>
    </section>
  </assessment>
</questestinterop>
```

I need to get the value of the yyy where fieldlabel = questiontype. How do I do that using linq ? Tried the following:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(assessmentXmlName);
XNamespace ns = "http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/ims_qtiasiv1p2";


var results = from main in document.Root
             .Elements(ns + "assessment")
             .Elements(ns + "section")
             .Elements(ns + "item")
             .Elements(ns + "itemmetadata")
             .Elements(ns + "qtimetadata")
             .Descendants("qtimetadatafield")
              select new
                  {
                      itemtype = (string)main.Element(ns + "fieldentry").Value,
                  };
```

Let me know

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387044.aspx

Comment: Also, indent your XML, it's impossible to tell what element ends where.

Comment: bobby - added what I tried.    Millimoose - indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To narrow your results to `fieldentry` fields where its sibling `fieldlabel` is "question_type" you can add a `where` clause:

```
var results = from main in document.Root
                            .Descendants(ns + "qtimetadatafield")
              where (string)main.Element(ns + "fieldlabel") == "question_type"
              select new
              {
                  itemtype = (string)main.Element(ns + "fieldentry")
              };
```

A couple of things to note:

- I removed all those `Element` calls. Unless you have a reason to be as specific as you were, such as duplicate element names nested in different elements, just grabbing the `Descendants` with the name you're interested in should suffice.
- When casting the element result to `string`, you shouldn't also be calling `.Value` since that would throw a `NullReferenceException` when that element is absent. I removed the `.Value` calls and kept the string casts.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, that was perfect.